# Should I use negotiate or negociate?

Tags: orthography

There are some word references and debates for "negociate".

Anyone knows if both are correct ? Where does the spelling "negociate" comes from ?

Comment: You need to supply those references on ELU.

Comment: What does your dictionary say?

Comment: Not happy about genref closure (though noref requires it). The first dictionary I looked in listed 'negociate' _unflagged_.

Answer (score 6):

The spelling "negociate" comes from a couple of centuries ago...

[image]

...but today it's *archaic, obsolete*.

Comment: .........Which?

Comment: @Edwin: Going by the definition [*The temporal label **obsolete** means that there is no evidence of use since 1755*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/whats-the-difference-between-archaic-and-obsolete) I suppose you'd have to say it's merely ***archaic***, but that doesn't really square with M-W's definition: ***archaic** means that "a word or sense once in common use is found today only sporadically or in special contexts"*. (I'd say there are *no* "special contexts" for it today, and any "sporadic" instances will simply be from people who can't spell for toffee).

Comment: I usually fudge by using a dash (A/B meaning 'A or B / both / somewhere in between ...).

Comment: @Edwin: Yes, but going by MW's definitions, I can't accurately use *either* term. Nevertheless, I positively refuse to say *negociate* is merely a "dated" spelling. I could maybe tolerate "hopelessly out-of-date" though.

Answer (score 2):

*Webster's Third New International Dictionary, Unabridged* lists "negociate" as an "archaic variant of negotiate", which means that it's not in common use anymore. Given that, I would use "negotiate."